# Migration Room 2.1.0 -> 2.2.3 (Android / Room / Java: Pre-packaged database has an invalid schema)

Tags: android, sqlite, android-studio-3.0

I am trying ot migrte to room 2.2.3 but I am expiriencing the issue:

```
 Process: , PID: 6854
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Pre-packaged database has an invalid schema: questionPart2Category(.models.db.entity.QuestionPart2Category).
 Expected:
TableInfo{name='questionPart2Category', columns={questionPart2CategoryId=Column{name='questionPart2CategoryId', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=1, defaultValue='null'}, categoryId=Column{name='categoryId', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, questionPartId=Column{name='questionPartId', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}}, foreignKeys=[ForeignKey{referenceTable='category', onDelete='NO ACTION', onUpdate='NO ACTION', columnNames=[categoryId], referenceColumnNames=[categoryId]}, ForeignKey{referenceTable='questionPart', onDelete='NO ACTION', onUpdate='NO ACTION', columnNames=[questionPartId], referenceColumnNames=[questionPartId]}], indices=[Index{name='index_questionPart2Category_questionPartId', unique=false, columns=[questionPartId]}, Index{name='index_questionPart2Category_categoryId', unique=false, columns=[categoryId]}]}
 Found:
TableInfo{name='questionPart2Category', columns={questionPart2categoryId=Column{name='questionPart2categoryId', type='Integer', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=1, defaultValue='null'}, questionPartId=Column{name='questionPartId', type='Integer', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, categoryId=Column{name='categoryId', type='Text', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}}, foreignKeys=[ForeignKey{referenceTable='category', onDelete='NO ACTION', onUpdate='NO ACTION', columnNames=[categoryId], referenceColumnNames=[categoryId]}, ForeignKey{referenceTable='questionPart', onDelete='NO ACTION', onUpdate='NO ACTION', columnNames=[questionPartId], referenceColumnNames=[questionPartId]}], indices=[Index{name='index_questionPart2Category_questionPartId', unique=false, columns=[questionPartId]}, Index{name='index_questionPart2Category_categoryId', unique=false, columns=[categoryId]}]}
```

I tried to compare every field / key / indice line by line but I did not see any difference.
Do you know guys what is happening?

Line by line (Expected and found)

```
questionPart2categoryId=Column{name='questionPart2categoryId', type='Integer', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=1, defaultValue='null'}, 
questionPart2CategoryId=Column{name='questionPart2CategoryId', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=1, defaultValue='null'}, 
questionPartId=Column{name='questionPartId', type='Integer', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, 
questionPartId=Column{name='questionPartId', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}
categoryId=Column{name='categoryId', type='Text', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}
categoryId=Column{name='categoryId', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, 

}, foreignKeys=[ForeignKey{referenceTable='category', onDelete='NO ACTION', onUpdate='NO ACTION', columnNames=[categoryId], referenceColumnNames=[categoryId]}, 
}, foreignKeys=[ForeignKey{referenceTable='category', onDelete='NO ACTION', onUpdate='NO ACTION', columnNames=[categoryId], referenceColumnNames=[categoryId]}, 
ForeignKey{referenceTable='questionPart', onDelete='NO ACTION', onUpdate='NO ACTION', columnNames=[questionPartId], referenceColumnNames=[questionPartId]}], 
ForeignKey{referenceTable='questionPart', onDelete='NO ACTION', onUpdate='NO ACTION', columnNames=[questionPartId], referenceColumnNames=[questionPartId]}], 
indices=[Index{name='index_questionPart2Category_questionPartId', unique=false, columns=[questionPartId]}, Index{name='index_questionPart2Category_categoryId', unique=false, columns=[categoryId]}]}
indices=[Index{name='index_questionPart2Category_questionPartId', unique=false, columns=[questionPartId]}, Index{name='index_questionPart2Category_categoryId', unique=false, columns=[categoryId]}]}
```

I;ve noticed only a difference with column order in found and expected but in Sqlite there is no way to define columns order.

Comment: did you find a solution?

Comment: The field type might be case sensitive... 'Integer' vs 'INTEGER?',